# Compare two CSV files by their creation date and save changes in another CSV with Powershell

Tags: file, powershell, csv, comparison, powershell-3.0

I'm having some issues creating a script that compares two CSV files by their creation time and saves the results as another CSV. I want to compare the files by which one is the newest. So, I have 2 directories, one is source and the other is destination. If the file in source is newer than destination, the script should get the filename, and copy it down to destination. Here is my code -

```
$source = import-csv -Path "c:\network.csv" 
$destination = import-csv -Path "c:\local.csv"

$output = @()  
   forEach ($Column in $source) {      
     $result = $destination | Where-Object {$Column.Name -eq $_.Name}  
     $CreationTime = if ($Column.CreationTime -lt $result.CreationTime) 
     { 
        write-host "Found Change"
        write-host  $Column.CreationTime
        write-host  $result.CreationTime

     }  
     $output += New-object PSObject -property @{  
       FileName = $Column.Name  
       CreationTime = $Column.CreationTime 
     }  
   }  
 $output | select-object FileName, CreationTime | Export-Csv -Path C:\Changes.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This code now seems to mark every entry as "found change" I would expect nothing to be in the text file because all of my files in my destination folder are newer than the source. Any help out there?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You were adding files to the $output object outside of your if statement, so everything was being added. This should work:

```
$source = import-csv -Path "c:\network.csv" 
$destination = import-csv -Path "c:\local.csv"

$output = @()
forEach ($row in $source) {      
    $result = $destination | Where-Object {$row.Name -eq $_.Name}  

    if ($row.CreationTime -lt $result.CreationTime) { 
        write-host "Found Change"
        write-host  $row.CreationTime
        write-host  $result.CreationTime
        $output += New-object PSObject -property @{  
            FileName = $row.Name  
            CreationTime = $row.CreationTime
        }
    }
}  

$output | select-object FileName, CreationTime | Export-Csv -Path C:\Changes.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I've also changed $Column to $row, as you're iterating over csv rows rather than columns.

Comment: Hi, the script is making a decision based on Creation time rather than the date and time. How would I alter this so that it takes the date into consideration also? Thanks